# Insert data exactly at specific place in unix files

Tags: unix

Consider I have one file with the data like below:

```
a  
b  
c  
d
```

second file data is:

```
f  
g  
h
```

I would like to insert the second file in first file like below:

```
a  
b  
f  
g  
h  
c  
d
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: What's the condition? On 3rd line? After `b`? Before `c`?

Comment: This sounds like a task for `sed`, `awk` or `perl` ... or a few other scripting languages.

Comment: its not about line number..its about After b and Before c. @fedorqui

Comment: Corrected title; "append" means to insert at the end.

Comment: First storing the exact line number which contains the value 'b' in one variable. var=`grep -n 'b' file1.txt|awk -F: 'print $1'|tr -d '\n'`. This gives me $var value as 2. Then `sed -i "$var r file2.txt" file1.txt` giving exact required result. Is there any other easier/short way than this? @Wooble

Answer (score 0):

sed can do the whole thing.  Specify the "address" part of the "r" command as a regexp rather than as a line number (which you currently have to extract with other tools):

```
sed -i -e '/b/r file2.txt' file1.txt
```